# Twitter Bootstrap 3 img-responsive edge-to-edge (bleed)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if the question title is correct, but I need help to get an image full width.

I have tried to add a css class like this:

```
.img-edge{
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

But it does not work.

[See example here](http://www.bootply.com/JrSqC2p2mN)

Anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Something like this? http://www.bootply.com/2ApGBH5zSJ

Comment: @Sam that's exactly what he had before.

Comment: @jrenk Scroll down then :)

Comment: @Sam oh god! My bad :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the image outside of the `.col-xs-12` element, like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>Some text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
        <p>Some text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
        <p>Some text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>
        <p>Some text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </p>

    </div>
        <img alt="Edge to edge!" src="http://dummyimage.com/1900x400/000000/fff" class="img-responsive img-edge">
 </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Example**](http://www.bootply.com/zT9Ul7agUr)